# Spurious error: Property inaccessible on ASPX page

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

On a legacy ASP.NET project I'm trying to maintain, there is what seems to be a spurious design-time error, namely, that a property is inaccessible. It is  declared Public. It works at runtime.

To troubleshoot, I added a new WebForm to the project to simplify things.

```
Public Class Logon2017
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

    Dim _Foo As Boolean

    Public Property Foo As Boolean
        Get
            Return True
        End Get
        Set(value As Boolean)
            _Foo = value
        End Set

    End Property


    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    End Sub

End Class
```

And on the ASPX page:

```
<%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeBehind="Logon2017.aspx.vb" Inherits="BlahBlah.Logon2017" %>
 <snip>
 .
 .
 .
<script type="text/javascript">
      var s = <%=Foo%>
 </script>
```

In the editor in Visual Studio 2015,  HTML view, "Foo" is underlined in red with the error that it is not declared.

What causes the ASPX page to be unable to find the Property declaration in the code-behind?

Is there some pointer in one of the project files that has gotten corrupted?

Comment: just to cross check try to create a hidden value in the `aspx` page with the `Foo` and assign the value in code behind

Comment: I changed it to Int32 from Boolean, since client-side javascript doesn't like "True". Client-side values are being properly assigned at runtime with the value returned by the server-side property.  The design-time error is spurious.  `<div>The property value is  <%=Foo%>  </div>` yields `The property value is 1`.

Comment: My property was simply returning a boolean, `return (1=1)` which resolves to `True`.  To eliminate that complication, I just switched the test property to Int32 and returned `1`.  I'm finding other reports on SO of spurious Intellisense errors, but so far, none of solutions in the heavily upvoted answers has worked for me.

Comment: Intelligence sometimes screws up. That's no surprise. What's important is if the application compiles and runs without error.